# Kuberentes Node port does not working on M1 Macbook pro

Tags: kubernetes

I started implementing the Kuberenetes for my simple app. I am facing issue when i use `NodePort`. IF I use `LoadBalancer` I can open my url. If I use `NodePort` it will take long time for trying to load and getting error `connection refused`. Below is my simple yaml file.

```
> POD yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod-webapp
  labels:
    app: webapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name:  app
    image: mydockerimage_xxx
```

```
> service.yaml

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  # Unique key of the Service instance
  name: service-webapp
spec:
  ports:
    # Accept traffic sent to port 80
    - name: http
      port: 80
      nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    app: webapp
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: check firewall rules, if port range `30000 - 32767` is open

Comment: my firewall was turned off but still it didn't work,  what i found something in github : https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193  which solved my issue partially.

Comment: if you have figured out the answer, consider answering it for future readers.

Comment: in above comment, i have shared the link :)

Comment: @fama please post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what I found something in GitHub : [Kubernetes NodePort](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193) which solved my issue partially.